# Using RODBC package in R and sqlQuery function to join 3 tables from a Database

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

can you help me to understand how i can create a `left join` between a `master table` `x1` and two other tables `x2` and `x3` using the `sqlQuery` function from the `RODBC` package in R.

After I setup the database connection I successfully can join two tables:

```
library RODBC

dataframe <-sqlQuery(conn,"
SELECT
sum(A1.revenue1),
sum(A1.revenue2), 
sum(A1.revenue3),
A2.SERVICE_TYPE_NAME
FROM
(FINANCE.x1 A1 LEFT JOIN CORE.x2 A2
ON (A1.YEAR_NUM = A2.YEAR_NUM 
AND A1.SERVICE_TYPE_KEY = A2.SERVICE_TYPE_KEY)
)
WHERE A1.YEAR_NUM = '2015' 
AND A2.SERVICE_TYPE_KEY='2'
GROUP BY A2.SERVICE_TYPE_NAME
")
```

but I fail when I try to bring a 3rd to the equation trying this:

```
dataframe <-sqlQuery(conn,"
SELECT
sum(A1.revenue1),
sum(A1.revenue2), 
sum(A1.revenue3),
A2.SERVICE_TYPE_NAME
FROM
(FINANCE.x1 A1 LEFT JOIN CORE.x2 A2
ON (A1.YEAR_NUM = A2.YEAR_NUM 
AND A1.SERVICE_TYPE_KEY = A2.SERVICE_TYPE_KEY)

FINANCE.x1 A1 LEFT JOIN BRAND.x3
ON (A1.brand_ID=A3.brand_ID))
WHERE A1.YEAR_NUM = '2015' 
AND A2.SERVICE_TYPE_KEY='2'
GROUP BY A2.SERVICE_TYPE_NAME
")
```

Comment: This is a purely SQL question. If the connection has worked once before, then when the SQL is sorted, R will be fine.

Comment: You might also want to tag with the version of SQL you are using.  In any case, I gave you a query below which should work.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I was struggling as i am connecting to DB2 and the RODBC package has a specific syntax in this case. Also am new to SQL to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Your second SQL needs to be cleaned up.  You only mention each table once when doing a join.  Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(A1.revenue1),
       SUM(A1.revenue2), 
       SUM(A1.revenue3),
       A2.SERVICE_TYPE_NAME
FROM FINANCE.x1 A1
LEFT JOIN CORE.x2 A2
    ON A1.YEAR_NUM = A2.YEAR_NUM AND
       A1.SERVICE_TYPE_KEY = A2.SERVICE_TYPE_KEY
LEFT JOIN BRAND.x3
    ON A1.brand_ID=A3.brand_ID
WHERE A1.YEAR_NUM = '2015' AND
      A2.SERVICE_TYPE_KEY = '2'
GROUP BY A2.SERVICE_TYPE_NAME
```